# Improve wordpress search

Tags: wordpress

How can i force the wordpress search show just the result with the full word no with the part of words.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress Search, even with plugins, is terrible.  I recommend building out a custom implementation of [Google Custom Search Engine](http://www.google.com/cse/) for your site.

It's pretty easy to integrate seamlessly with Wordpress and it blows away WP search results in both ease of use and accuracy of results.  It does have a small cost associated (between $100 and $250 a year, if you have a small to medium sized site), but it is totally worth it.

Comment: No custom implementation needed when using this simple plugin to integrate Google Custom Search into your WordPress site/blog: __[Google Custom Search](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-cse/)__

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure how you would manage that, but you take an alternative route and use a plugin such as this [one](http://www.scottkclark.com/wordpress/search-engine/).

Comment: i had searche many plugin, but can't configure this, all plugins search part-word

Comment: You should be able to configure this plugin fairly well from functionality to styling. It spiders your site and creates an index in the same fashion a search engine, like Google would. Than it uses a weighted algorithm to calculate page ranking. The search results it returns function much like Google and it should be searching based on whole words.

Answer (score 0):

Try [WordPress › Search Unleashed « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-unleashed/) and then tweak your search form to include "" around the search term to return just full word hits.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use WP Search http://wpsear.ch/ .